# Call to a member function saveAs() on a non-object in yii2 file upload

Tags: php, file, file-upload, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using kartik fileUpload extension for uploading of files in yii2, As soon as i select a file and submit, im getting

> Call to a member function saveAs() on a non-object

I have checked other post regarding this issue but its not helping,

My View code..

```
 <?php  echo $form->field($documents, 'sars_certificate')->label(false)->
  widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'showCaption' => true,'showRemove' => true,'showClose' => true,
        'showPreview' => true,'uploadAsync' => true,
        'showUpload' => false,'maxFileSize'=> 2000,'autoReplace'=> true, 
        'placeholder' => 'Select a File...',],]); ?>
```

My model code..

```
 [['sars_certificate'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg,pdf,jpeg']
```

And My controller code..

```
  public function actionCreate()
  {   
  $model = new Projects(); 
  $documents = new ProjectDocuments();    

$borrower_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
  $code = $model->accessCode(10);
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
  {
   //All $model related things will bw done

  //In this im doing file upload
  $documents->borrower_id = $borrower_id; 
  $documents->project_id = $code;    
  $documents->save(false);  

  $documents->sars_certificate = UploadedFile::getInstances($documents,'sars_certificate');

  $documents->sars_certificate->saveAs('user/purchase_order/' . $documents->sars_certificate->baseName . '.' . $documents->sars_certificate->extension);
  $documents->sars_certificate = $documents->sars_certificate;
  $documents->save(false); 

         return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
```

I have given `if($documents->validate()){ **** }`. But its not coming under if condition itself, so i removed it. Now it says above error..

Please anyone help in this, im wasting lot of time on this...

Comment: Please paste whole code of that particular action.

Comment: remove that image upload code. and use this. let me know what happened. `if(UploadedFile::getInstance($documents, 'sars_certificate')){
  $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($documents, 'sars_certificate');
  $path = "user/purchase_order/".$image->name;
  if($image->saveAs($path)) {
    echo "success";
  } else {
    echo "not success";
  }
} else {
  echo "sme other problem";
} 
die;` @Salman

Comment: It is printing success, and the image is stored in that folder, but not stored in db. Now what i want is "sars_certificate" should have uploaded file name is db, and "sars_certificate_enc" should have encrypted data.. like random generated number.. to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Previously, it was storing to folder? @Salman. Don't worry. I will try my best to help you come out of the problem.

Comment: Remove first `$documents->save(false);` (before UploadInstance) @salman

Comment: No it was not storing to folder. ok i removed save(false);

Comment: So, One problem fixed of yours as now it is saving to folder. Check my latest answer. It has little modification. Go through it. @Salman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** To avoid duplicate images, append `time()` in image name.

**2)** Remove `$documents->save(false);` before `UploadInstance`.

```
public function actionCreate() {
  $model = new Projects();
  $documents = new ProjectDocuments();

  $borrower_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
  $code = $model->accessCode(10);
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    //All $model related things will bw done
    //In this im doing file upload
    $documents->borrower_id = $borrower_id;
    $documents->project_id = $code;


    if(UploadedFile::getInstance($documents, 'sars_certificate')){
      $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($documents, 'sars_certificate'); 
      $imageName = time().$image->name;
      $path = "user/purchase_order/".$imageName; 
      if($image->saveAs($path)){
       $documents->sars_certificate = $imageName;
      }
    }

    $documents->save(false);
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
  }
}
```

**Update**

```
public function actionCreate() {
  $model = new Projects();
  $documents = new ProjectDocuments();

  $borrower_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
  $code = $model->accessCode(10);
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    //All $model related things will bw done
    //In this im doing file upload
    $documents->borrower_id = $borrower_id;
    $documents->project_id = $code;


    if(UploadedFile::getInstance($documents, 'sars_certificate')){
      $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($documents, 'sars_certificate');
      if($image){
        $imageName = time().$image->name;
        $path = "user/purchase_order/".$imageName; 
        if($image->saveAs($path)){
         $documents->sars_certificate = $imageName;
        }
      }
    }

    $documents->save(false);
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
  }
}
```

Comment: The image is getting stored. But its not saving in db.

Comment: Again Copy and paste my code and tell @SalmanRiyaz . I changed few lines. May be that not affected. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: No its not saving, the borrower_id and project_id is stored, but image name is not stored.

Comment: Tell me one thing. `sars_certificate` is in **Projects** model or in **ProjectDocuments** model? And, why this line is used `$model = new Projects();` when, it is not used anywhere in the code @SalmanRiyaz?

Comment: "sars_certificate" is in **ProjectDocuments** , and  $model = new Projects(); has got some code for storing its data.. like some fields

Comment: Yes it is saving. borrower_id and project_id.

Comment: yes no its storing..  i removed these two lines from model.. `[['sars_certificate'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg,pdf,jpeg'],`  and `public $sars_certificate;`

Comment: Update is not working, if i don’t select any file and click on update an empty value is stored in db.

Comment: Please go through my **Update** section of my answer. @SalmanRiyaz

Comment: Done buddy, Thank u soooooo much.. :)